# Display placeholder text from Language resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, localization

I have a text area to show the description and my model for the same looks like

```
[Display(Name = "CopyrightHolder_AdditionalInfo_Label", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
```

And in Razor i am using the form like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdditionalInfo)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AdditionalInfo, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "5", @placeholder = "i wnat to load from resource file this text", @maxlength = "545" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdditionalInfo)
</div>
```

I am also planning to show a placeholder on this text area which should load from resource file 
Is there any way to do the same ?

Comment: You could always read the value and assign it to a `ViewBag` or view model property and use `new { placeholder = ViewBag.PlaceHolder }` (or did you want to do this using a DataAnnotation?

Comment: ViewBag or Model property will work  for me :) Not sure about DataAnnotation. Is any advantage of using that?

Comment: It just means you could use something like `[PlaceHolder(Name = "...", ResourceType = typeof(Resource)]` but its a lot of work (means creating your own `Attribute` that implements `IMetadataAware` and creating your own HtmlHelper extension method to generate the html) - probably not worth it unless you going to be using it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add it like below:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(
    model => model.AdditionalInfo,
    new {
        @class = "form-control",
        @rows = "5",
        @placeholder = @Resources.Strings.YourKeyString,
        @maxlength = "545"
    }
)
```